# Magento2 - How to place order using graphql?

Tags: magento2, place-order, graphql

I am following this tutorial to process cart / checkout for placing orders using `graphql`. [Magento GraphQl Tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/tutorials/checkout/index.html).
And we have installed stripe on magento(backend).

So we are facing issue while placing order.

- Customer logs in get a authentication token
- Create empty cart
- Add product to cart
- Set billing and shipping address for cart
- **Set payment method to stripe_payments (without card details)**
- **Placing order receiving error here**

How can I set payment method and debit card details to cart using `graphql` and place successful test order?

Comment: do you want to place order using 

which payment method

1)check money order or 
2)Online payment

Comment: @prabhakaran7 using online payment (stripe) we've installed it and working fine over website. but don't know how to place using graphQl's cart?

Comment: stripe payment is already has graphql api right?

Comment: @prabhakaran7 we've installed magento on admin side, now we want to place a test order using magento graphql, but didn't know from where to pass payment card credentials.

Comment: altair extension install your browser --

for firefox 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/altair-graphql-client/

then load your magento url

--- like this https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/208/208844.png?modified=1543520945

Comment: @prabhakaran7 its no need to install extension we've already this environment, and running graphql successfully.just here to ask the payment process nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all steps ( 1 to 4 ) have been done without any issue. Please check the below steps for the mutation by which you can set the payment method and place the order.

Example: Use the setPaymentMethodOnCart mutation to set the payment method for your order. The value **checkmo** ("Check / Money order" payment method code) was returned in the query.

```
mutation {
      setPaymentMethodOnCart(input: {
          cart_id: "{ CART_ID }"
          payment_method: {
              code: "checkmo"
          }
      }) {
        cart {
          selected_payment_method {
            code
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Response:**

If the operation is successful, the response contains the code of the selected payment method.

```
{
  "data": {
    "setPaymentMethodOnCart": {
      "cart": {
        "selected_payment_method": {
          "code": "checkmo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Set payment method and place order**
Use the setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder mutation to set the payment method and place the order.

**Request:**

```
mutation {
  setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder(input: {
      cart_id: "{ CART_ID }"
      payment_method: {
          code: "checkmo"
      }
  }) {
    order {
      order_id
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

If the operation is successful, the response contains the order ID.

```
{
  "data": {
    "setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder": {
      "order": {
        "order_id": "000000001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure "setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder mutation" is not deprecated in the current version of Magento 2.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have to use all the ten steps:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/tutorials/checkout/checkout-place-order.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=search_page&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=order